Shortest Way In C# To Assign A Variable If Another Variable Is Not Null
Apologies in advance as these types of questions have come up many times before - I have searched through quite a few and cannot find the answer to my specific scenario.
I have a one-liner as follows:-
MyNullableString1 = MyNullableInt2 is not null ? regexMatch.Groups[MyNullableInt2.Value].Value : null;

I only want to set MyNullableString1 to the value in the regex match as long as MyNullableInt1 isn't null otherwise I want to leave MyNullableString1 as null.
Is there a way to make this expression simpler?
This might be the shortest way of expressing it, but I have a feeling it could be simpler using maybe the null conditional operator ?. somewhere (although I have tried it in a few places and it hasn't worked!).

Remove the not and swap the branches.

Write a extension method for Regex that does that logic? Not shorter but prettier to some eyes.

var MyNullableString1 = MyRegexExtension(MyNullableInt2) ;
try to be moduler instead of shorter

thanks everyone for the suggestions, they are all better than mine! i was really hoping to be able to reduce the terniary to a 2-parter using maybe one of the newer operators, but i think that's not possible now. however, i really like the extension suggestion as i already have a few extensions for this kind of thing so i will def go with that :) ralf you mentioned it first, can you make an answer of your comment then i can mark it as accepted?

How about this:
MyNullableString1 = MyNullableInt2.HasValue ? regexMatch.Groups[MyNullableInt2.Value]?.Value : null;

